# Create a Google Classroom assignment in which students cannot attach files

Tags: google-forms, attachment, google-classroom

How can I create an assignment that only allows students to submit their answers via an attached form?

I tend to assign questions to be answered via Forms, but sometimes students answer by attaching a file. I want to prevent that.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time it's not possible to block the attachment feature of Google Classroom assignments from the Google Classroom user interface.

Specific reference? Google very rarely include on their [Help Centers](https://support.google.com) information about things  that can't be done . Before this post ;) the best shot was to look through the old and new official help forums

- old: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-education
- new: https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/community

Workarounds? The usual,

- return the assignment to the student telling them that they should follow the assignment instructions
- use the Guardian feature to involve students guardians (parents, tutors, etc) on helping students to successfully follow the assignment instructions
- assign a low grade

General reference

- [Google Classroom Help Center](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom)